# How to insert leading "zero" on single digit date and time values in text file?

Tags: batch-file

Anybody can help me how to append "zero" if there is single digit date/time from txt file output below:

```
C|000001|56600|MMB-W1S0033|R|||||16-3-2|9:35:1|
P|000001|56600|MMB-W1S0033||||||16-3-2|9:35:2|
C|000001|56600|MMB-W1S0210|R|||||16-3-2|9:35:3|
P|000001|56600|MMB-W1S0210||||||16-3-2|9:35:4|
```

Change to become below?

```
C|000001|56600|MMB-W1S0033|R|||||16-03-02|09:35:01|
P|000001|56600|MMB-W1S0033||||||16-03-02|09:35:02|
C|000001|56600|MMB-W1S0210|R|||||16-03-02|09:35:03|
P|000001|56600|MMB-W1S0210||||||16-03-02|09:35:04|
```

Comment: Are you **really** still using MS-DOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Next time please first try something by yourself.

Please modify the file name and path in third line of this little batch script.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "InputFile=C:\Temp\TestFile.txt"
if not exist "%InputFile%" goto :EOF

set "TempFile=%TEMP%\TestFile.tmp"
if exist "%TempFile%" del "%TempFile%"

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    if "!Line:~-3,1!"  == ":" set "Line=!Line:~0,-2!0!Line:~-2!"
    if "!Line:~-6,1!"  == ":" set "Line=!Line:~0,-5!0!Line:~-5!"
    if "!Line:~-9,1!"  == "|" set "Line=!Line:~0,-8!0!Line:~-8!"
    if "!Line:~-12,1!" == "-" set "Line=!Line:~0,-11!0!Line:~-11!"
    if "!Line:~-15,1!" == "-" set "Line=!Line:~0,-14!0!Line:~-14!"
    if "!Line:~-18,1!" == "|" set "Line=!Line:~0,-17!0!Line:~-17!"
    echo !Line!>>"%TempFile%"
)

move /Y "%TempFile%" "%InputFile%"
endlocal
```

This batch file simply checks if a character at a specific position relative to end of line is equal a compared and expected character and inserts a leading zero if this is not the case because the date/time value right of position in line has only 1 digit.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?` ... most important here to understand the substitutions.
- `setlocal /?`

And see also Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: hi mofi..really thanks for your prompt help, it works as expected...honestly I'm not too good in dos-batch programming :(